# How can I test a simple Server -- Client Application on my own machine at home?

Tags: java

I want to test this simpel server-client application on my own machine at home. How can I run this in Eclipse and then see if the other side can see my message. I want to at some point be able to make a chat window that anyone could have on their machine and send messages to anyone that is online that is linked into the chat window.

But first I have to be able to see that I have a connection. Should I install a server on my computer, or someone told me that there was a server already installed on my computer but I just had to have windows turn it on. (Windows 7)

**Question: How can I test this client-server on my computer at home?**

Code:

Client Side:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DateClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
            "running the date service on port 9090:");
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 9090);
        BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = input.readLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Server side:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Code I want to Add for new message:

```
 out.println("Hello Doug, how are you!);
```

This will not show in my message box when it shows up on the screen. Is 127.0.0.1 always the IP address that needs to be entered when testing from eclipse or how would I change this around so that I could let the user determine their own IP address.

Comment: sooner or later, you'll want to review what happens by creating a TCP server socket and connecting to it; what ports the client and the `accept()`ed socket use, etc. after you have learned this, you will know what "server" actually means, and hopefully you'll be more confident in writing your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any server.

In Eclipse (assuming your coding is correct), you can run multiple programs (Java files with a main method) simultaneously.

First, say DateServer -> Run As -> Java Application
Next, say DateClient -> Run As -> Java Application

To run this, you don't need any additional server, but Win 7 might ask you for permissions to unblock these programs from accessing the network. You should say yes to these permissions.

If you want to get a feel of separate client and server, this might be better

1. Keep the DateClient and DateServer in two different projects
2. Compile both projects as JARs
3. Open two different DOS consoles and run these two applications in these separate DOS consoles.

Comment: When you say open them in two different DOS consoles does it just open in the DOS console if you type in the name. I hate to say it but it has been a while since I have used a DOS console.

Comment: Isn't the JAR just the executable on the desktop?

Comment: It depends on how the JAR is built. You can package it as a runnable JAR and yes, you can just double click on it (like a desktop app) and it will run. If not, you will have to use the following command to run it on the console:

java -cp path/to/myjar.jar com.my.app.DateServer

This will tell Java: Run the main method from the DateServer class that is contained in myjar.kar. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can just open two terminals.  For the `DateClient`, just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the address.  If you really must use Eclipse, then you can run one of the program from Eclipse and the other from a terminal.

Comment: And where is the terminal to be found. What are the other options instead of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Client Side :

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ClientSide {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeUTF("Hello");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection failed");
    }
}
}
```

Server Side :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class ServerSide {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
        System.out.println("waiting for connection...");
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(ss.accept().getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Successfully Connected\n" + dis.readUTF());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Server Not Started : " + ex);
    }
}
}
```